# Null Checking React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm currently having a big issue with null checking and i don't understand why ...

here my snippet where the problem is located:

```
  getUser(data).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result == null);
    if (result == null) {
      console.log("IS NULL");
    } else {
      console.log(NULL);
    }
  }
```

here's `getUser` for reference:

```
function getUser(uid) {
  return firebase
    .database()
    .ref(`/users/${uid}`)
    .once("value")
    .then(snapshot => {
      console.log(snapshot);
      if (snapshot === null) return null;
       return snapshot;
    });
}
```

`snapshot` can be either and object like so :

```
[16:34:18] Object {
[16:34:18]   "email": "user@example.com",
[16:34:18]   "walletAmount": 0,
[16:34:18] }
```

or `null`

but my condition is not working as expected in the snippet.

if `snapshot` is equal to the object mentionned before, i have the following output :

```
console.log(result == null); // false
```

but when `snapshot` is null, output is still:

```
console.log(result == null); // false
```

i've tried so much things like `Object.propotype.hasOwnProperty.call(result, "email")` with no success...

Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do it by calling

`if (result.val() && result.val().email)`

i think because `snapshot` is a special object from firebase i couldn't do it by using hasOwnProperty (maybe because of inheritance) either way problem solved !